# Switch authorization mechanism in Apigee

Tags: api, authentication, apigee

My architecture considers an ApiGateway (ApiGee) that dispatches requests to a service behind.

All APIs (http and rest) have an authorization mechanism. So, the client needs to authenticate itself to an IAM before operate with my APIs.

In order to avoid bad security design, all services behind the ApiGateway accept authenticated requests.

For (technical and business) requirements reasons, I need to use internal/external different authentication mechanisms: when a client sends a request, that has to contains the authorization information provided by IAM1. Instead, the services behind accept authenticated APIs that contains Auth information that came from IAM2.

For the translation, I create a service 'translation-token-service' that exposes an API for implementing the token translation.

My desiderata is to "link" ApiGee to the 'translation-token-service' in order to let the clients to continue to use the authorization from IAM1 and the behind services to continue to use the authorization information from IAM2: when a request arrives, ApiGee should invoke the 'translation-token-service' for having a token with IAM2 authorization information, injects them into the request and dispatches it to the right behind service.

NB: the token conversation made by ApiGee should be in some how cached (I don't care about the storage type). So if a client makes two call with the same token, the first invocation asks to convert the token, the second one doesn't, for performance reason.

NB: IAM1 is not oidc compliant, IAM2 does.

How can I implement this flow?